# Looking for a number of true/specific sequences in a log file

Tags: matlab, logging, sequence

I have a task to do for my master thesis and I really need your help because I'm stuck and I can't work on statistics without doing it.

The first thing to do was to find the amount of times there is a specific sequence of 8 numbers in a series of hundreds of numbers. You can find bellow a DL to see how the log file looks like. You have to read only column "Code". The true sequence can be whether "44 22 33 21", "13 43 43 21", or "14 34 14 32", depending on the log file (so only 4 numbers).

For this, my friend found the script and it works fine :

```
close all;
[FileName,PathName]=uigetfile('*.log','Select File');
startRow=input('Which line does the data start at?');
addpath(PathName);
BLOC_1 = Import_Sequence(FileName,startRow,inf);
sequence = [4;4;2;2;3;3;2;1];
n = 0;
vrai = 0;
ii = 1;
jj = 8;
Taille = size(BLOC_1);
Fin = Taille(1);
Taillesequence = size(sequence);
Blocksequence = Taillesequence(1);
Limite = Fin-Blocksequence;
while n < Limite
    morceau = BLOC_1(ii:jj);
    tf = isequal(morceau,sequence);
    if tf == 1
        vrai=vrai+1;
        n=n+1;
        ii=ii+1;
        jj=jj+1;
    else
    n=n+1;
        ii=ii+1;
        jj=jj+1;
    end
end
vrai
```

It works, indeed, but I need an extra information. In the log file, you have the column "Code" separated 2 times by a series of numbers ≠ "1","2","3","4", and so it splits the file into 3 blocks/parts.

Here is the problem: the script above gives me the number of true sequences **for the whole file**, but what I want is the number of true sequences for **each block**. And this is where I need your help. How to find the number of true sequences for each block, in order to have 3 values? Is it possible to create a proper script for that?

An example of the log file is [here](https://mega.nz/#!is4hRA7R!XksN3-VNtwv7DXZLijDGWT96WRYnT1wJjObbfXEFXu4).

Comment: Didn't you already ask this before?

Comment: Yes, but it was full of mistakes. So I've created a new one, completly different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need it to work for each block, you can find line numbers which contain block information and perform the operation on each block,

```
fid = fopen('path\to\log\file\file.log');
line = 0;
lineNumbersWithBLOC = [];

while ~feof(fid)
  tLine = fgetl(fid);
  line = line + 1;
  if ~isempty(strfind(tLine, 'BLOC_'))
     lineNumbersWithBLOC = cat(1, lineNumbersWithBLOC, line);
  end
end

fclose(fid);
```

Once you have the line numbers which contain `BLOC_`, you can run the working code to find the pattern.

Comment: Thank you for answering !

So if I understood, this script you've just created will find the line in order to analyse true sequences for each block. 

But how to include it into my script ? Will it find the number of true sequences for each block, in order to have 3 values ?

Comment: Does anyone can help ? :/

Comment: @Baronnet, I would this in the following way: 
1. Process each line 
2. Split line using `strsplit`, which will return a cell array of column values at each line 
3. Keep record of the column you are interested in and look for pattern. 4. If you find an instance of `BLOC_` (using `strfind` as shown above), you know you have reached end of a block. 

Hope that helps.